# How do I script converting a .psd or .ai file into multiple sized PNGs?

Tags: image-manipulation

For iPhone programming, I need my application icon in many sizes.

Rather than have my designer export one by one, is there a way I can script photoshop, illustrator, or just use Python or something to convert a .PSD or .AI file into several different sizes of .PNG?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to create an action in Photosop (sort of making a Macro) and doing a batch in the File -> Automate -> Batch option.

[Check this link out for more info](http://www.creativemac.com/2002/04_apr/tutorials/psbatch.htm) (Mac based tutorial but i've done it in the PC version).